# Is it possible to send HTTP GET Requests from a Simulink Block?

Tags: matlab, http, simulink

basically the title says it all. I'm working on a model that needs (there is no way around it) to load data from a website, parse it and pass it onto another block. I thought I could use an S-Function written in `C++`, which didn't properly work, then I tried to use `webread()`
which also didn't work in Simulink because I can't use extrinsic functions on the device this will run on.

I thought I could work around it by downloading the file externally and then reading it through `fscanf`but it turned out that Matlab CODER doesn't support that as well.

After putting 2 1/2 days into this now, I'm asking myself whether it is even possible to do something like an HTTP Request through a Simulink block. That's why I went here to ask that question. Thanks for every answer!

Comment: Why didn't the S-Function work?

Comment: @PhilGoddard Tried to use the cURL Library bit it couldn't be included. - Probably will try to get back to that, but that's not the question. Should it work through the s-function though ?

Comment: Assuming the data being returned into Simulink is a Simulink data type then you can do anything that can be done in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it with a C++ S-Function by now.
I also created a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/njoye/matlab-sfunc-http/tree/master) for it. If you're stuck with the same problem as I was, try to take a look at this. I'm pretty sure it will help you.